# How to debug python code using vs code by attaching to a running container (without Dockerfile)?

Tags: python, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to debug python code in D:\Tools\sima\source after running :
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/mnt -w /mnt sima-sdk:latest /bin/bash
Then I open VSCODE and do attach to running container.

This opens a second VS Code window in that container as shown in the picture below : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stbJk.png)

Then I select the python interpreter within the docker /usr/bin/python3
Now I want to run the debugger. I creates a  launch .json file as below

```
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python: Current File",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${file}",
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "justMyCode": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

and my python code is very simple :

```
    a = 4
    b = 7
    c = a* b
    print("c is equal to", c)
    print("Hello test 1 ")
    print("Hello test 2")
```

When I set a breakpoint in the python code editor and run the debugger, nothing seems to happen although the variable and watch windows are showing up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J2pY.png)

Can I get hep to understand what I am doing wrong  if anything please?
I have googled a lot without results
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set your `"justMyCode:false"`. This can make your code sotp at breakpoint:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "justMyCode": false,
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

Comment: That did not fix my problem. BTW I have created a ./devcontainer/devcontainer.json file with following content : {
    "image": "sima-sdk:latest",
    "forwardPorts": [3000,3001],
    "customizations": {
      // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
      "vscode": {
        // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
        "extensions": [
          "ms-python.python",
          "ms-vscode.cpptools"
      ]
      }
    }
  } ->open a folder in the running container from VSCODE and run debugger.--> debug proces runs but its frozen.

Comment: @Eddy De Waegeneer Did you use this [icon](https://imgur.com/a/oRS5NAk)?