# Debug in Visual Studio Code using docker

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm new on Visual Studio Code and Docker. I write api in .net and run using docker. But I was unable to debug it. It is not hitting the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode follows task model. The IDE can be configured to debug/run multiple frameworks/languages. Tasks.json file is used to configure project actions. Read about it here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks
Read about configuring visual studio code tasks to debug various project types here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common

Refer to https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/06/24/vs-code-net-debug-a-net-web-app-in-visual-studio-code

Also, potentially this is a duplicate question - [How to debug python code using vs code by attaching to a running container (without Dockerfile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73140377/how-to-debug-python-code-using-vs-code-by-attaching-to-a-running-container-with)